# Crazy SQL question: How to do a sort of cross apply with a pivot?

Tags: sql, pivot, cross-apply

Customer has shortcuts in their data where they have a **quantity of records** in a field. When I parse them, I need to manufacture records, one for each quantity, incrementing the "identifier" by 7 days (because the number represents a date.
Example: a single product that is on sale for four weeks and I need four records, one product for each week.

<kbd>[Event Number]</kbd> 
 <kbd>[Classification]</kbd> 
 <kbd>[Weeks Running]</kbd> 
  <kbd>[Some Data]</kbd>  
 <kbd>2009 11 29 00</kbd>  
        <kbd>1</kbd>         
         <kbd>1</kbd>       
 <kbd>runs one week</kbd> 
 <kbd>2009 12 06 00</kbd>  
        <kbd>2</kbd>         
         <kbd>1</kbd>       
 <kbd>runs one week</kbd> 
 <kbd>2009 12 13 00</kbd>  
        <kbd>1</kbd>         
         <kbd>4</kbd>       
<kbd>runs four weeks</kbd>
 <kbd>2009 12 20 00</kbd>  
        <kbd>2</kbd>         
         <kbd>4</kbd>       
<kbd>runs four weeks</kbd>

Somehow I need to turn this data into the following with a view (sql select) (all in the same table, white space included to see parts:

<kbd>[Event Number + Classification]</kbd> 
    <kbd>[Some Data]</kbd>    
          <kbd>2009 11 29 01</kbd>          
 <kbd>runs for one week</kbd>  One week thus one record.
          <kbd>2009 12 06 02</kbd>          
 <kbd>runs for one week</kbd> 
          <kbd>2009 12 13 01</kbd>          
<kbd>runs for four weeks</kbd> Repeats 4 times incrementing date by 7
          <kbd>2009 12 20 01</kbd>          
<kbd>runs for four weeks</kbd>
          <kbd>2009 12 27 01</kbd>          
<kbd>runs for four weeks</kbd>
          <kbd>2009 01 03 01</kbd>          
<kbd>runs for four weeks</kbd>
          <kbd>2009 12 20 02</kbd>          
<kbd>runs for four weeks</kbd> Repeats 4 times incrementing date by 7
          <kbd>2009 12 27 02</kbd>          
<kbd>runs for four weeks</kbd>
          <kbd>2009 01 03 02</kbd>          
<kbd>runs for four weeks</kbd>
          <kbd>2009 01 10 02</kbd>          
<kbd>runs for four weeks</kbd>

My thoughts are to have some sort of pivot cross apply sql code?

Comment: I just want to +1 for the formatting...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have a cheap answer for you. You use a "pre-rendered" `Weeks` table to create a query-based loop. You would need to put enough weeks into it to cover your expected range of scenarios.

```
[Week]
1
2
3
4
```

Then you join your query on `[Weeks Running]` to this table, using the inequality `OriginalTable.WeeksRunning <= Weeks.Week`. You end up with one row per week.

You deduce the date by adding `Weeks.Week * 7` days to the date embedded in your event number.

Answer (score 3):

This is something that would probably be simpler to do on application-side rather than database-side, but I'll give it a shot...  This requires a database supporting CTEs, which I don't happen to have on hand, so this is untested.

```
WITH RECURSIVE expandedTable(eventNumber, classification, index, count, someData)
AS (
    SELECT eventNumber, classification, 1, weeksRunning, someData
    FROM originalTable
    WHERE weeksRunning > 0
  UNION ALL
    SELECT eventNumber + 7, classification, index + 1, count, someData
    FROM expandedTable
    WHERE index < count
)
SELECT eventNumber, classification, someData
FROM expandedTable;
```

Comment: Ah, I love SQL but I hate SQL. It's so true that this is better done app-side. You have to bend over backwards and often end up with less-than-readable queries when trying to pull off something that's just not SQL's thing. I can't see a nice elegant SQL-based solution to this particular problem.